# Icon svg não ocupa 100% da área na tag svg

Tags: svg

Estou com problemas em uma dos meus ícones em svg, ele não ocupa os 100% de `width` e `height` da tag `svg` e isso acaba me atrapalhando em alguns alinhamentos com textos e outros ícones.

Segue o código:

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol id="question-list" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path class="st0" d="M112.9,24.6H22.4C10,24.6,0,34.6,0,47v90.6C0,149.9,10,160,22.4,160H113c12.3,0,22.4-10,22.4-22.4V47
        C135.3,34.6,125.3,24.6,112.9,24.6zM14.6,47c0-4.3,3.5-7.8,7.8-7.8H113c4.3,0,7.8,3.5,7.8,7.8v90.6c0,4.3-3.5,7.8-7.8,7.8H22.4c-4.3,0-7.8-3.5-7.8-7.8C14.6,137.6,14.6,47,14.6,47z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M191.9,63h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3s-3.3-7.3-7.3-7.3H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3C184.6,59.7,187.9,63,191.9,63z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M191.9,99.5h247.2c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3s-3.3-7.3-7.3-7.3H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3S187.9,99.5,191.9,99.5z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M504.7,121.5H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3s3.3,7.3,7.3,7.3h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3C512,124.8,508.7,121.5,504.7,121.5z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M504.7,212.2H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3s3.3,7.3,7.3,7.3h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3C512,215.4,508.7,212.2,504.7,212.2z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M191.9,263.3h247.2c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3c0-4-3.3-7.3-7.3-7.3H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3C184.6,260,187.9,263.3,191.9,263.3z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M504.7,285.2H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3s3.3,7.3,7.3,7.3h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3C512,288.5,508.7,285.2,504.7,285.2z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M29.3,123.3c0,1.9,0.8,3.8,2.1,5.2c1.4,1.4,3.2,2.1,5.2,2.1c1.9,0,3.8-0.8,5.1-2.1l25.9-25.9l25.9,25.9c1.4,1.4,3.2,2.1,5.1,2.1s3.8-0.8,5.2-2.1c1.4-1.4,2.1-3.2,2.1-5.2c0-1.9-0.8-3.8-2.1-5.2L78,92.3l25.9-25.9c2.8-2.8,2.8-7.5,0-10.3c-1.4-1.4-3.2-2.1-5.2-2.1c-1.9,0-3.8,0.8-5.1,2.1L67.7,82l-26-25.9c-1.4-1.4-3.2-2.1-5.2-2.1c-1.9,0-3.8,0.8-5.2,2.1c-1.4,1.4-2.1,3.2-2.1,5.2c0,1.9,0.8,3.8,2.1,5.2l25.9,25.9l-25.9,25.9C30,119.5,29.3,121.4,29.3,123.3z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M112.9,188.3H22.4C10,188.3,0,198.4,0,210.7v90.6c0,12.3,10,22.4,22.4,22.4H113c12.3,0,22.4-10,22.4-22.4v-90.6C135.3,198.4,125.3,188.3,112.9,188.3z M14.6,210.7c0-4.3,3.5-7.8,7.8-7.8H113c4.3,0,7.8,3.5,7.8,7.8v90.6c0,4.3-3.5,7.8-7.8,7.8H22.4c-4.3,0-7.8-3.5-7.8-7.8C14.6,301.3,14.6,210.7,14.6,210.7z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M49.7,292.6c1.4,1.6,3.4,2.5,5.5,2.5c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0c2.2-0.1,4.3-1.3,5.6-3.2l43.7-63.6c1.1-1.6,1.5-3.5,1.2-5.5c-0.4-1.9-1.4-3.6-3-4.7c-1.2-0.8-2.6-1.3-4.1-1.3c-2.4,0-4.7,1.2-6,3.2l-38.3,55.9L42,261.4c-1.4-1.6-3.4-2.5-5.5-2.5c-1.7,0-3.4,0.6-4.8,1.8c-3,2.6-3.4,7.2-0.8,10.3L49.7,292.6z"/>
  </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>



<svg>
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="myicons.svg#question-list"></use>
</svg>
```

Não consegui fazer ele aparecer aqui, mas segue uma imagem de como esta.

[image: Ele não ocupada a área azul inteira como os demais]

[image: Aqui esta ok ocupando toda área azul][image: Aqui tb esta ok ocupa toda área]

Comment: Vai usar o SVG como icones em um HTML? Fazendo uso de CSS sprite?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento na vdd so to add ele direto no HTML não estou usando como sprite.

Comment: Eu recomendaria a abordagem CSS sprite, usando o SVG, assim poderá reaproveitar um mesmo SVG para inumeros icones e pode usar o use apenas para trocar a cor do fill.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim sim mas nesse caso eu optei por não usar como sprite, porem to com problema nesse icone especifico =/  e isso problema me ferra em alguns alinhamentos.

Answer (score 0):

Não é a solução perfeita, mas vc pode deixar o `symbol` com `preserveAspectRatio="none"` assim ele ocupa 100% no X Y de controlar colocando um `width` e `height` do SVG na mão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso, tem que fazer um ajuste fino no `viewbox` do SVG, mudei para `viewBox="0 25 512 300"`... Esse problema aconteceu pq quando o ícone foi desenhado ele não estava ocupando o tamanho completo do `canvas`

E o ícone não apareceu no exemplo da sua pergunta pq vc deixou a referencia do xLink errada, deveria ser apenas `xlink:href="#question-list"`

**OBS:** é uma boa prática colocar `style="display: none"` no `<svg>` onde vc está construindo seu *pattern* de **symbols**!, se não ele vai ocupar espaço na tela!

```css
.teste {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display: none">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="question-list" viewBox="0 25 512 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path class="st0" d="M112.9,24.6H22.4C10,24.6,0,34.6,0,47v90.6C0,149.9,10,160,22.4,160H113c12.3,0,22.4-10,22.4-22.4V47
        C135.3,34.6,125.3,24.6,112.9,24.6zM14.6,47c0-4.3,3.5-7.8,7.8-7.8H113c4.3,0,7.8,3.5,7.8,7.8v90.6c0,4.3-3.5,7.8-7.8,7.8H22.4c-4.3,0-7.8-3.5-7.8-7.8C14.6,137.6,14.6,47,14.6,47z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M191.9,63h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3s-3.3-7.3-7.3-7.3H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3C184.6,59.7,187.9,63,191.9,63z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M191.9,99.5h247.2c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3s-3.3-7.3-7.3-7.3H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3S187.9,99.5,191.9,99.5z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M504.7,121.5H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3s3.3,7.3,7.3,7.3h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3C512,124.8,508.7,121.5,504.7,121.5z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M504.7,212.2H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3s3.3,7.3,7.3,7.3h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3C512,215.4,508.7,212.2,504.7,212.2z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M191.9,263.3h247.2c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3c0-4-3.3-7.3-7.3-7.3H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3C184.6,260,187.9,263.3,191.9,263.3z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M504.7,285.2H191.9c-4,0-7.3,3.3-7.3,7.3s3.3,7.3,7.3,7.3h312.8c4,0,7.3-3.3,7.3-7.3C512,288.5,508.7,285.2,504.7,285.2z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M29.3,123.3c0,1.9,0.8,3.8,2.1,5.2c1.4,1.4,3.2,2.1,5.2,2.1c1.9,0,3.8-0.8,5.1-2.1l25.9-25.9l25.9,25.9c1.4,1.4,3.2,2.1,5.1,2.1s3.8-0.8,5.2-2.1c1.4-1.4,2.1-3.2,2.1-5.2c0-1.9-0.8-3.8-2.1-5.2L78,92.3l25.9-25.9c2.8-2.8,2.8-7.5,0-10.3c-1.4-1.4-3.2-2.1-5.2-2.1c-1.9,0-3.8,0.8-5.1,2.1L67.7,82l-26-25.9c-1.4-1.4-3.2-2.1-5.2-2.1c-1.9,0-3.8,0.8-5.2,2.1c-1.4,1.4-2.1,3.2-2.1,5.2c0,1.9,0.8,3.8,2.1,5.2l25.9,25.9l-25.9,25.9C30,119.5,29.3,121.4,29.3,123.3z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M112.9,188.3H22.4C10,188.3,0,198.4,0,210.7v90.6c0,12.3,10,22.4,22.4,22.4H113c12.3,0,22.4-10,22.4-22.4v-90.6C135.3,198.4,125.3,188.3,112.9,188.3z M14.6,210.7c0-4.3,3.5-7.8,7.8-7.8H113c4.3,0,7.8,3.5,7.8,7.8v90.6c0,4.3-3.5,7.8-7.8,7.8H22.4c-4.3,0-7.8-3.5-7.8-7.8C14.6,301.3,14.6,210.7,14.6,210.7z"/>
        <path class="st0" d="M49.7,292.6c1.4,1.6,3.4,2.5,5.5,2.5c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0c2.2-0.1,4.3-1.3,5.6-3.2l43.7-63.6c1.1-1.6,1.5-3.5,1.2-5.5c-0.4-1.9-1.4-3.6-3-4.7c-1.2-0.8-2.6-1.3-4.1-1.3c-2.4,0-4.7,1.2-6,3.2l-38.3,55.9L42,261.4c-1.4-1.6-3.4-2.5-5.5-2.5c-1.7,0-3.4,0.6-4.8,1.8c-3,2.6-3.4,7.2-0.8,10.3L49.7,292.6z"/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>



<svg class="teste">
  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#question-list"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -3):

Tenta colocar dentro de uma div, e deixa essa div com height e width 100%. Nunca tive problema com svg, ele sempre ocupou 100% mantendo a relação. Se não der joga um object-fit: fill no svg.